# Can anyone tell me how to write code for suppressing the following errors in htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Can anyone tell me how to write code for suppressing the following errors in an htaccess file?

- Warning
- E-Notice
- Fatal Error

Comment: Easy, fix the errors. Hiding them doesn't do you any good. They're **errors**. That means you need to figure out what's wrong and correct them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display error messages caused by your PHP script you can include these lines of code:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
php_value error_reporting 0
php_flag display_errors Off
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `error_reporting()` function sets to enable errors.

```
<?php

    // Report simple running errors
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

    // Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
    // variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

    // Report all errors except E_NOTICE
    // This is the default value set in php.ini
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    // Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // Report all PHP errors
    error_reporting(-1);

    // Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

    ?>
```

Comment: And you can set these in `.htaccess` as well. `php_value error_reporting 0` for example